# Why does the 70s porno film not look like a 70s film?

Tags: realism, the-nice-guys

In Nice Guys (2016), they accidently play a porno movie at a car show, as can be seen in this picture:

[image]

It looks clearer and more modern than a 70s film. If it is a 70s reel, where does the modern beauty come from?

Comment: Are we sure it's really a '70s film?

Comment: @ChanandlerBong The real world movie The Nice Guys is set in the 70s, and the in-universe porno film was produced only shortly before the events portrayed in the movie, so it's definitely no later than the 70s.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist My question was whether it's a real porno film from the '70s or fake one, created for the purpose of the movie. If it's the latter it doesn't surprise me, that it has _modern beauty_, regardless if we are talking about the actress or the film itself.

Comment: Why would it be a real porn film from the 70s? It's got the modern actors in it.. and it has lines that relate specifically to the issues of the catalytic converter being discussed in the film.

Comment: In what way is this clip "clearer and more modern" than you would expect a 70s film to be?  I haven't seen Nice Guys, but from this screenshot, nothing strikes me as particularly anachronistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because audiences in 2016 want to see 2016 standards of beauty and not 70s standards of beauty. In-universe,  it is still a 70s skin flick.

If you are talking about the technical quality of the film, they just declined to go all out and add clicks, pops, static or any other sign of 70s movie technology aside from the vintagging and color cast of 70s technicolor. The technical accuracy was not high on the films to do list.

Comment: Mentioning "standards of beauty" has confused me, because I thought the question was about the visual quality of the in-"universe" film, rather than how the actress looks.

Comment: @anthony ops use of "modern beauty" made me think he's talking about how the actress looks. She doesn't look like a real 70s movie star. She looks like a 2000s star in retro clothing.